# Problems with Caser Cipher and .isalpha

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

```
eingabe = Text(window, width=200, height=4)
eingabe.pack()


def c2n():
    alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
    k = 3
    c = ''
    code = ''
    try:
        code = str(eingabe.get('1.0',END))
        code = code.lower()
        code = code.replace("\n","")
    except:
        label1.configure(text="Error!")
    finally:
        if code.isalpha():
            for z in code:
                if z == ' ':
                    c += z
                elif z in alphabet:
                    c += alphabet[(alphabet.index(z) + k) % (len(alphabet))]
            label1.configure(text=(str(c)))
        else:
            label1.configure(text="only letters please")
```

I recently started with Python and one of my first tasks was to create a Caesar cipher encrypter/decrypter GUI with Tkiner. This is only a snippet from my code.

So I wanted to use Text not Entry to give my users more space to fill in stuff, but I realized that now my users can't hit the next rot in the text field without creating a `\n`. The problem with that is that I check with code `.isalpha()` if the text only contain letters, and thats not working any longer.

Now I am looking for a new way to check for letters only or find a new way to handle the `\n`.

Any positive criticism and feedback for the rest of the garbage code would be nice also, but as I said I recently started with Python and english is not my native language.

Comment: You should separate the GUI from the processing.

Comment: Do you want to prevent a newline from being entered (which is possible), or do you want to allow newlines, but adjust your algorithm to accept them, ignore them, or convert them to a space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just test for `isspace`:

```
def crypt(text, k=3):
    alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
    result = []
    for z in text.lower():
        if z.isspace():
            result.append(z)
        elif z in alphabet:
            result.append(alphabet[(alphabet.index(z) + k) % (len(alphabet))])
       else:
           raise AssertionError()
    return ''.join(result)


def c2n(text):
    try:
        label1.configure(text=crypt(eingabe.get('1.0',END)))
    except AssertionError:
        label1.configure(text="only letters please")
```